# Query on python function that does the same as if statement

Tags: python

I have written a solution for the below question.

Q) Let's try to write a function that does the same thing as an if statement:

```
def if_function(condition, true_result, false_result):
    """Return true_result if condition is a true value, and false_result otherwise."""
    if condition:
        return true_result
    else:
        return false_result
```

This function actually does not do the same thing as an if statement in all cases. To prove this fact, write functions c, t, and f such that one of the functions returns the number 1, but the other does not:

```
def with_if_statement():
    if c():
        return t()
    else:
        return f()

def with_if_function():
    return if_function(c(), t(), f())

def c():
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"

def t():
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"

def f():
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

---

Solution:

```
>>> def c():
    return 2 < 3

>>> def t():
    return 2 < 3

>>> def f():
    return not 2 < 3

>>> print(with_if_function())
True
>>>
```

---

My question:

Can you please confirm, if my solution is correct?

or

Do you think am yet to understand this question correctly?

Comment: What is the point of implementing such a function if you still use `if` in it?

Comment: @HerrActress because `if` is a statement and `if_function` is an expression. The latter can be used in places the former cannot.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor This makes sense. I guess I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @HerrActress That's okay, I think I did too :)

Comment: @MatthewTrevor I tried writing the solution, But i did not think that this expression can be used in places): Such kind of conversion leads to an application which has only functions??? and Do you like that?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor May be am still not clear about the meaning of statement in the question: 'This function actually does not do the same thing as an if statement in all cases.'--- Can you help me understand?

Comment: @Sham: With the `if-else` statement, the function `t` will only be called if `c` returns `True`, while the function `f` will only be called if `c` returns `False`. With the `if_function` version, both `t` and `f` will be called. Try putting `print('calling t')` in function `t` and `print('calling f')` in `f`, then running `with_if_statement` and `with_if_function` and the difference will be more apparent.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor when you say: 'With the if_function version, both t and f will be called.' --- called you mean as arguments here ----if_function(c(), t(), f())

Comment: @Sham: yes, `t` and `f` will both be called there _regardless_ of the return value of `c`, while in the `if-else` statement only one will be called _depending_ on the return value of `c`.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor In merlin update, i see beencalled attribute, but am unable to see that in >>>dir(f)  --- do you think python3 doesnt show this?

Comment: @Sham `f` will only have the `beencalled` attribute after it has been run once.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor Here we are calling c() t() f() twice, first time when pass arguments to if_function(c(), t(), f()) and second time within def if_function(c,f,t): if c(): return t() else: return f()

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation of the question is that you have to write `c()`, `f()`, and `t()` such that `with_if_statement()` and `with_if_function()` return different results.

With the definitions you have given, they currently both return `True`, which indicates your solution is not correct.

I believe there are almost certainly multiple solutions, but here is one possible solution:

```
def c():
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
    return True

def t():
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
    if not hasattr(f, "beencalled"): 
        return 1
    return 0

def f():
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
    f.beencalled = True
    return 0

print(with_if_function())
print(with_if_statement())
```

Here `with_if_function` returns `1`, while `with_if_statement` returns `0`, thus satisfying the requirement that **one of the functions returns the number 1, but the other does not**
.

Comment: Whoever left a downvote on this answer, I am requesting some explanation. The question is explicitly asking for his answer is correct or incorrect, not asking for an actual solution.

Comment: if i say >>>dir(f)  i dont see 'beencalled' attribute

Comment: @merlin2011 Shouldn't the code in `t` and `f` be the other way around?

Comment: @Sham, That is because `beencalled` will not exist until `f()` has been called at least once. Instead of using an attribute, I could have used a globally scoped variable, but I was not sure if your requirements allowed for that, so I hid it inside the function instead.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor, The only requirement is that one function returns 1 and the other does not. It does not say which function should return which. When you combine the code in my answer with the code provided by the OP, you will see a `1` printed and also a `0` printed. I think if you switched it, you would probably just switch which function returned what, but I have not tested that way, so I cannot say.

Comment: @merlin2011 In the question, i see no difference between the definition of function with_if_statement() & with_if_function(). Both are doing same work. i think the author is asking, [This function actually does not do the same thing as an `if statement` in all cases.] Question is to prove it. In the above answer, we are comparing two functions with_if_function() and with_if_statement(), by giving definitions to f() c() t(), unlike the question given

Comment: @overexchange, I have shown you a counterexample for which the function and the `if statement` are not the same. That is sufficient to prove that they are not the same.

Comment: @merlin2011 this statement in your answer `print(with_if_statement())` is not an `if statement`, right? Instead it is doing the same work as `print(with_if_function())`

Comment: It is calling your function which uses an if statement instead of the function.  The print is just to display.  The logic is correct without the print.

Comment: @merlin2011 am trying to say that `with_if_statement()` is not an `if statement`. Instead it is running the same logic that `with_if_function()` is running. See the definitions of both functions, they are doing same job.

Comment: In your post you clearly show an if statement in the definition of `with_if_statement`.

Answer (score 2):

What you may be missing is that you're passing the *result* of your functions into `if_function` and not the functions themselves. So this:

```
if_function(c(), t(), f())
```

...is equivalent to:

```
_c = c()
_t = t()
_f = f()
if_function(_c, _t, _f)
```

That is, your `condition` function, `true_result` function and `false_result` function are all called *before* `if_function`.

With a little extra effort, though, it's easy to make it more similar:

```
def delayed_call(x):
    # if x is a function, call it and return the result, otherwise return x
    return x() if hasattr(x, '__call__') else x

def if_function(condition, true_result, false_result):
    if delayed_call(condition):
        return delayed_call(true_result)
    else:
        return delayed_call(false_result)
```

And then `if_function(c(), t(), f())` becomes `if_function(c, t, f)`

Comment: I do not think he's asking how to "fix" it, although that may be the next part. He is asking for a counterexample that breaks his implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
def if_function(condition, true_result, false_result):
    """Return true_result if condition is a true value, and
    false_result otherwise.

    >>> if_function(True, 2, 3)
    2
    >>> if_function(False, 2, 3)
    3
    >>> if_function(3==2, 3+2, 3-2)
    1
    >>> if_function(3>2, 3+2, 3-2)
    5
    """
    if condition:
        return true_result
    else:
        return false_result


def with_if_statement():
    """
    >>> with_if_statement()
    1
    """
    if c():
        return t()
    else:
        return f()

def with_if_function():
    return if_function(c(), t(), f())
```

The question requires that, write 3 functions: `c`, `t` and `f` such that `with_if_statement` returns `1` and `with_if_function` does not return 1 (and it can do anything else)

At the beginning, the problem seems to be ridiculous since, logically, `with_if_statement` returns and `with_if_function` are same. However, if we see these two functions from an interpreter view, they are different.

The function `with_if_function` uses a call expression, which guarantees that all of its operand subexpressions will be evaluated before `if_function` is applied to the resulting arguments. Therefore, even if `c` returns `False`, the function `t` will be called. By contrast, `with_if_statement` will never call `t` if `c` returns False. (From UCB website)

```
def c():
    return True

def t():
    return 1

def f():
    '1'.sort()
```