# Adding a new attribute to Python object?

Tags: python

Being from OOPS background, It looks strange to see below code from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855455/query-on-python-function-that-does-the-same-as-if-statement)

```
def f():
    f.beencalled = True
    return 0
```

My question:

1)
From the above code,
Is `f` a reference variable pointing to an object `f` of `class 'function'`?

2)
We add a new attribute `beencalled` to an object `f`, so now `'function'` class does not have this attribute `beencalled` defined and we say that object `f` is an object of `class 'function'`? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a slightly different note, you can change this behavior for custom classes.

```
class FooBar(object):
    __slots__ = ["foo","bar","baz"]
    # if you don't define __slots__, you can add attr to the object as needed
    # if you do, the object can only contain those attributes.
    def __init__(self,foo=None,bar=None,baz=None):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz
    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a FooBar with id {0} with foo: {1.foo}, bar: {1.bar}, baz: {1.baz}".format(id(self),self)

>>> a = FooBar("a","B","CCC")
>>> print(a)
I'm a FooBar with id 47260256 with foo: a, bar: B, baz: CCC
>>> a.spam = "eggs"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    a.spam = "eggs"
AttributeError: 'FooBar' object has no attribute 'spam'
```

Alternately, without defining `__slots__`:

```
class BooFar(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a BooFar with the following attributes:\n{}".format(self.__dict__)

>>> b = BooFar()
>>> print(b)
I'm a BooFar with the following attributes:
{}
>>> b.spam = "eggs"
>>> print(b)
I'm a BooFar with the following attributes:
{'spam': 'eggs'}
```

Comment: @Sham I don't even remotely understand your question....  Mostly you use `__slots__` to minimize a memory footprint. Implementing `__slots__` makes your object MUCH smaller than the same object that implements a `__dict__` instead (which is the default)

Comment: adam so we can add/delete attributes to objects of a class, but after adding/deleting attribute, will that object be still called as object of that class.

Answer (score 5):

1) Yes:

```
>>> def f():
        print(type(f))

>>> f()
>>> <class 'function'>
```

2) The `function` class does not have a new attribute, but the object `f` does. Adding or removing attributes to/from an object does not affect which attributes other objects of that class will have:

```
>>> class A: pass
>>> a = A()
>>> a.var = 7
>>> b = A()
>>> b.var
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    b.newvar
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'var'
```

Classes are much more flexible in python than in Java or C++. Objects can have attributes not defined in their class, or even lack attributes that were defined in their class! Look at this:

```
>>> class A:
def __init__(self, a):
    self.var = a


>>> obj = A(7)
>>> del obj.var #deletes the var attribute from obj, does not change the A class
>>> obj.var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    obj.var
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'var'

>>> obj2 = A(6)
>>> obj2.var #obj2 is a new object, so the fact we deleted var from obj doesn't affect it
6
```

EDIT: after a bit of searching I found an explanation for why this behavior was chosen ([source](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/adding-support-for-user-defined-classes.html)):

> To implement user-defined objects, I settled on the simplest possible
>   design; a scheme where objects were represented by a new kind of
>   built-in object that stored a class reference pointing to a "class
>   object" shared by all instances of the same class, and a dictionary,
>   dubbed the "instance dictionary", that contained the instance
>   variables.
>
> In this implementation, the instance dictionary would contain the
>   instance variables of each individual object whereas the class object
>   would contain stuff shared between all instances of the same class--in
>   particular, methods. In implementing class objects, I again chose the
>   simplest possible design; the set of methods of a class were stored in
>   a dictionary whose keys are the method names. This, I dubbed the class
>   dictionary. To support inheritance, class objects would additionally
>   store a reference to the class objects corresponding to the base
>   classes. At the time, I was fairly naïve about classes, but I knew
>   about multiple inheritance, which had recently been added to C++. I
>   decided that as long as I was going to support inheritance, I might as
>   well support a simple-minded version of multiple inheritance. Thus,
>   every class object could have one or more base classes.
>
> In this implementation, the underlying mechanics of working with
>   objects are actually very simple. Whenever changes are made to
>   instance or class variables, those changes are simply reflected in the
>   underlying dictionary object. For example, setting an instance
>   variable on an instance updates its local instance dictionary.
>   Likewise, when looking up the value of a instance variable of an
>   object, one merely checks its instance dictionary for the existence of
>   that variable. If the variable is not found there, things become a
>   little more interesting. In that case, lookups are performed in the
>   class dictionary and then in the class dictionaries of each of the
>   base classes.

Comment: valek so object can have proeprties that it's class does not contain in general? and for that  matter, extra behaviour as well? which class does not have?

Comment: @Sham Yes. They can also _lack_ attributes that their class has in general!

Comment: VALEK But we are tied with class and class instances kind of concept in java/c++, in what sense are these paradigms true? java does not allow doing this

Comment: @Sham but Python is not Java or C++, so there is no reason for it to be tied to concepts in those languages.

Comment: @Sham It has to do with the design philosophies of the different languages. Java emphasizes type safety and encourages restriction of potentially error-causing behavior, while Python emphasizes flexibility and freedom and lets programmers do pretty much whatever they want.

Comment: valek do u think object lacking or having more attr than class is more  close to real world so python encourages this approach? BECASUE AN OCEAN CREATURE CAN HAVE 10 EXHAUSTIvE(SAY) PROPERTIES BUT SHARK MAY HAVE SUBSET OF THEM

Comment: @Sham I don't know what the motivation for designing the language this way was. There's a small discussion regarding this phenomenon [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/210065).

Comment: valek Can we also do dynamic method creation as well for an object of some class?

Comment: @Sham I found an article discussing class design in python. I believe it answers your question. Also, functions are objects in python, so they can be treated like regular attributes.

Comment: valek can u paste the link of this article?

Comment: @Sham The link is in my answer. Look for the blue text in parentheses.

Comment: @Sham "in what sense are these paradigms true": a class is simply an object template; it provides a method for creating objects and identifies a type. This is true for python and languages with "classes" in general. Static typing (as in Java and C++) is a separate aspect.

Comment: @nmclean Does OOP paradigm conceptually support object having extra attribute/behaviour that it's class does not possess?

Comment: @Sham Python classes conceptually follow OOP because there is a type hierarchy with method inheritance. It's true that the ability to change the set of attributes could break polymorphism (if a user of a superclass expects a certain attribute that was removed by a subclass), but keep in mind that enforcing attributes doesn't eliminate the problem either (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#A_typical_violation). As always it's the programmer's responsibility to decide when and how to use language features to design the most practical and understandable systems.

Comment: @nmclean as you said, enforcing the attributes, doesn't eliminate the problem, that wiki link is abit complex stuff to me to understand. but after you add/delete attributes from an object, will that object can still be called as object of that particular class? Because object is not in compliance wit the class attributes.

Comment: @Sham Well, it isn't accurate to say the object doesn't comply with "class attributes", because the instance attributes aren't part of the class definition, they're only assigned within methods (mainly `__init__`). And as you know, methods can be overridden. If you think about it, the situation is not so different in statically typed languages, because the internal fields are usually hidden in favor of getter and setter methods -- and there is nothing stopping you from deciding that a certain property is not valid in a subclass, and overriding the getter and setter to throw an exception.

Comment: @nmclean assuming we have a single class and an instance of that class got created. Do u think adding/deleting an object be in compliance with that class? In static type languages like java, Subclassing & overriding does not change the number of attributes that a parent class or subclass has, ofcourse private access specifiers does not get inherited by subclass, but why do we relate this to an object being  compliance with a class?

Comment: @Sham As long as `type(obj) is TheClass` is true, and the class's methods can handle the state of the object (including existence of attributes), I would say the object is "in compliance" with the class -- but it's a subjective term.

Answer (score 1):

`f()` in just an instance of `types.FunctionType`, and instances can have their own attributes.

Adding an attribute to an instance won't affect its class unless you've overridden the `__setattr__` method of that class and doing something evil there.

```
>>> import types
>>> def func(): pass
>>> isinstance(func, types.FunctionType)
True
```

Comment: >>> def f():pass

>>> type(f)
<class 'function'>
>>> how do i understand this?

Comment: @Sham `f` is a function that takes no arguments, does nothing and returns `None`. The type of this function is `<class 'function'>`.

Comment: @Sham Understand what?